# RAD Studio debugger raises exceptions and stops frequently

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

When debugging Mac Apps by RAD Studio, debugger raises execptions and stops frequently with message : "Invalid remote api";
I also reported this issue to Quality Central.
I have maked a descriptor video [here](http://doxy.phphost.biz/MacBCBCrash.swf).
I use Windows 7 as host os and osx 10.6 or 10.7 on vmware workstation.

Does anybody have an idea about it?
Thankyou.

Comment: Submit a support query as well as your QC report.

Comment: My QC report here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=105582

Comment: If you want help submit a support case. QC is not enough.

Comment: Go here: http://www.embarcadero.com/support

Comment: Did you try just updating Windows?

Comment: My OS is Win7 SP1 (also on XP), Do you compile and debug C++ Builder for Mac OS (VMWare) successfully? This problem olso occures on XE3! I have a commercial project (Mac,Win), and I have been ignored debugging on Mac and just use logging for debug purpose.

Comment: This has nothing to do with windows. the IDE simply crashes and raises exceptions. There are obivously a lot of bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this bug finally has been fixed in XE6!